# React - accessing selected option on button click?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have something like this

```
handleClick:function(){
    // click logic
},
render: function(){
  return (
    <select>
        <option value="a">A</option>
        <option value="b">B</option>
    </select>
    <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Get Selected Value</button>
  );
}
```

How do I get the value of the `select` element when I click the `button`?

Answer (score 3):

You add a reference to the select

```
handleClick:function(){
    var value = React.findDOMNode(this.refs.mySelect).value;
},
render: function(){
  return (
    <select ref="mySelect">
        <option value="a">A</option>
        <option value="b">B</option>
    </select>
    <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Get Selected Value</button>
  );
}
```

Comment: Or alternatively, make `select` controlled.

Comment: @FelixKling - phew, I had to look up the part about controlled components in the docs again, and its' still a bit beyond me, I've just started to play around with React.

Comment: No worries, it took me a while to get my head around as well :) if you have any question and think I might be able to help you, shoot me a message! The idea behind a controlled form control is that the value is always provided by the owner, which in turn means that the owner has to listen to any changes the user does to the control, and update its internal state. I'm on the phone, otherwise  I would provide a complete example.

Comment: @FelixKling - thanks, I've literally just started trying it out, tried it once before but these clientside libraries that mix js and html in weird ways just rub me the wrong way, same thing with Angular, I really don't like it, but React seems a little better, but at the same time more complicated and a little hard to grok? I know where to find you !

Answer (score 0):

While you can get a hold of the DOM node of the select and find out the current value, I find it simpler to use component state for this. Something like this:

```
var React = require('react/addons');

var App = React.createClass({
  mixins: [React.addons.LinkedStateMixin],
  getInitialState: function () {
    return {
      option: 'a'
    };
  },
  handleClick: function () {
    alert(this.state.option);
  },
  render: function () {
    return (
      <select valueLink={this.linkState('option')}>
          <option value="a">A</option>
          <option value="b">B</option>
      </select>
      <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Get Selected Value</button>
    );
  }
});
```

The `LinkedStateMixin` mixin makes sure that any changes to the select box will automatically sync that value to the components state. But also the other way around, you can update the state and `LinkedStateMixin` will make sure that the select box gets the new value.