# Get select option value on submit with React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

What is the best way to get the vaule of the select option when I click on the submit button in react?

Would I need to add an onChange to the select option as well?

```
var UIPrintChart = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function () {
        return {
            value: 'PNG'
        }
    },
    handlePrint(event) {
        if (this.state.value == 'PNG') {
            console.log('Hello PNG');
        }
        if (this.state.value == 'JPEG') {
            console.log('Hello JPEG');
        }
        if (this.state.value == 'PDF') {
            console.log('Hello PDF');
        }
        if (this.state.value == 'SVG') {
            console.log('Hello SVG');
        }
    },
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <select>
                    <option value="PNG">PNG Image</option>
                    <option value="JPEG">JPEG Image</option>
                    <option value="PDF">PDF Document</option>
                    <option value="SVG">SVG Vector Image</option>
                </select>
                <button className="uk-button uk-button-mini" onClick={this.handlePrint}>Export Chart</button> 
            </div>
            )
    }
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React - accessing selected option on button click?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29761194/react-accessing-selected-option-on-button-click)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend using refs instead of state.

```
<select ref="imageType">
  <option value="PNG">PNG Image</option>
  <option value="JPEG">JPEG Image</option>
  <option value="PDF">PDF Document</option>
  <option value="SVG">SVG Vector Image</option>
</select>

handlePrint() {
  if (this.refs.imageType) {
    console.log(this.refs.imageType.value);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 13):

> Would I need to add an onChange to the select option as well?

**Yes**, like this:

```
 <select onChange={(e) => this.setState({ value: e.target.value })}>
    <option value="PNG">PNG Image</option>
    <option value="JPEG">JPEG Image</option>
    <option value="PDF">PDF Document</option>
    <option value="SVG">SVG Vector Image</option>
 </select>
```

Comment: Upvoted - I have also given an answer that is slightly more optimal in terms of performance, however your answer is also technically correct :)

Answer (score 11):

Yep, you'll have to add an `onChange` handler for the `select` element. Leo provided an answer for you but probably isn't optimal as every time the event fires, a new callback is created. Although at the scale your app probably doesn't require this level of optimisation. Anyway, I would probably rewrite things to extend from the React.Component class:

```
import React from 'react';

class UIPrintChart extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      value: 'PNG'
    };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handlePrint = this.handlePrint.bind(this);
  }

  handlePrint() {
    if (this.state.value) {
      console.log(this.state.value);
    }
  }

  handleChange(e) {
    this.setState({ value: e.target.value });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <select onChange={this.handleChange}>
          <option value="PNG">PNG Image</option>
          <option value="JPEG">JPEG Image</option>
          <option value="PDF">PDF Document</option>
          <option value="SVG">SVG Vector Image</option>
        </select>
        <button className="uk-button uk-button-mini" onClick={this.handlePrint}>Export Chart</button> 
      </div
    );
  }
}

export default UIPrintChart;
```

I also simplified your `handlePrint` function, but you can implement this however you like :) Hope this helps!